# Running Flask with mod_Wsgi through virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, server, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

On a sever at work (Apache 2.2.3), I am trying to activate my first ever Hello World in with Flask. I can't find logs for errors in any typical recommended locations.

I have made a virtualenv in `/home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire`

This is my rrfexpire.wsgi script:

```
activate_this = 
'/home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from rrfexpire import app as application
```

This was added to Apache httpd.conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess rrfexipre user=apache group=apache threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /blog /home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire/rrfexpire.wsgi

<Directory /home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire>
WSGIProcessGroup rrfexpire
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And this is the my Hello World test (rrfexpire.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
  return "Hello, World!"

print hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=True)
```

I was hoping to see the results when I use my Chrome browser at http://departmentServer.company.com/rrfexpire/  but I get nothing.  The whole nrDee directory is set to 777 permission to eliminate permissions from preventing this from running.  And I tried to confirm Python version (2.7.13) and mod_wsgi compatibility with the command

```
#ldd venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
```

One line from that result reads "libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/bin/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0", which I interpreted to mean mod_wsgi is correctly compiled for Python2.7

I'm new to this and have been heavily in Flask and mod_wsgi documentation and feel stuck.
Can you please provide guidance on what to check next?
Thanks!
-nrDee

Comment: You have the application mounted at ``/blog`` not ``/rrfexpire`` so need to change your URL or the ``WSGIScriptAlias``.

Comment: Thanks!  
I updated `WSGIScriptAlias` to `/rrfexpire`, restarted Apache, and received the 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Your keen eye made me find another typo.  
I updated `WSGIDaemonProcess` to `/rrfexpire`, restarted httpd service, and still have 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Why are you updating ``WSGIDaemonProcess``? That doesn't need to match the mount point. It does need to match what is used for ``WSGIProcessGroup``. If you are getting 500 errors, the reason will be in the Apache error logs, so make sure you are looking there and add the details of the error if it isn't obvious.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting below @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: I figured out how to pull the logs. Incredible! I fixed a few syntax errors and am now stuck at this one:

Comment: [Sun Dec 10 04:22:02 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166] File "/home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire/rrfexpire.wsgi", line 5 [Sun Dec 10 04:22:02 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166] from rrfexpire import app as application <br/> [Sun Dec 10 04:22:02 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166] ^ [Sun Dec 10 04:22:02 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166] SyntaxError: invalid syntax –

Comment: You have possibly saved non non standard characters in the file. Is too hard to tell from that. Also quite possible the cause of the problem is in prior lines. For example, not balancing parenthesis.

Comment: I found a missing `)` and corrected it and am at an even more scary sounding error.  @GrahamDumpleton   Google is short on information for this one as applied to my application of implementing Flask in a virtualenv

Comment: [Sun Dec 10 05:08:09 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166]     execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
[Sun Dec 10 05:08:09 2017] [error] [client 10.192.151.166] NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

Comment: The ``execfile()`` builtin doesn't exist in Python 3. You will need to find the Python 3 equivalent. Better still, read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html and learn about better way of setting up virtual environments with mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @GrahamDumpleton.  I can recite documentation from memory now, and am making progress!  I have so much to learn

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution but it is not perfect because my URL is not updating unless httpd service is restarted.  But at least I can see my HelloWorld now!

My current rrfexpire.wsgi script is baffling to me because it is using the Python3 syntax in a py2.7 virtualenv:

```
activate_this = 
'/home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire')
from rrfexpire import app as application
```

And here is my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName company.server.com:80

  WSGIDaemonProcess rrfexpire user=apache group=apache
  WSGIScriptAlias /rrfexpire /home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire/rrfexpire.wsgi

<Directory /home/nrDee/public_html/rrfexpire>
WSGIProcessGroup rrfexpire
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For details on source code reloading see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution without using “obscure scripts” is to simply refer to the python within your venv at the beginning of your .wsgi file:

```
#!/path/to/your/venv/bin/python
```

Simple. Logical. No magic. Wish I had thought of it earlier than I did.